# 2 Guards 3 Doors

Tags: logic, recreational-mathematics

You approach 2 guards and 3 doors. You know that 2 of the 3 doors will lead you to inevitable death and the other leads you to safety. You also know that when asking the guards about the doors, they will only indicate one of the doors and that you may ask one question to both guards or 2 questions, one to each guard.

This is all written on a tablet before you. However as you approach the guards to begin asking questions, they speak and give information not on the tablet.

The first guard, named 1, says, "One of us only tells the truth..."
To which the second guard says, "... and the other only tells lies."

They then command you to begin your questioning.

**How do you pick the safe door with absolute certainty?**

**Clarification:** A guard, in this situation, is either a knight (who always tells the truth) or a knave (who always lies).

Comment: Ignore my previous comment (sort of, though the overall principle is valid) -- this would likely belong better on the Puzzling Stack Exchange (https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: @JohnDouma If we knew one guard was truthful and the other was a liar, that would work. But we do not know that to be the case, because we got that information from the possibly lying guards!

Comment: Not enough information, I think. The guards could be normal people who sometimes lie, sometimes tell the truth, and sometimes give wholly logically inconsistent statements.

Comment: Where did this puzzle come from? I do not see how to reconcile those two statements with any of the four configurations knight-knight, knight-knave, knave-knight, or knave-knave. In other words, the problem statement seems to contradict itself.

Comment: @RohitPandey You seem to be claiming there is one knight and one knave. I think that is not possible to reconcile with the problem statement. I think the whole setup is not possible.

Comment: As the author of this question, I will say that when I first saw it, I was beginning to doubt that the setup was possible. However, I soon began to think that I was overthinking it, which is why I wanted to see other people's input.

Comment: Why does nobody ever wonder "is the *tablet* telling the truth?"

Answer (score 2):

You ask guard 1, "If I were to ask guard 2 if or not door 1 is safe, what would he say?" Flip whatever answer you get and that's the status of door 1. If you conclude it's safe, walk past. Otherwise, ask the same question for door 2 and repeat the process.

Comment: Doesn’t work, the lying guard can just answer something on the lines of “purple flamingo”

Answer (score 2):

Well, we know the guards are both knaves. If they're both knights, the second one lied, and if they're one of each, they both told the truth.

So you only need one question. Ask either of them to point to a door that leads to death. They will point to the safe door.